# C/Objective-C delete and nil with comma between - what does it do?

Tags: objective-c, c, memory-management, struct, xcode9

I upgraded an Objective-C project with some C underpinnings to Xcode 9, which is generating a new warning:

> possible misuse of comma operator here [-Wcomma]

I'm actually not sure what this statement is doing, so I'm not sure how to handle the warning. What is the effect of this statement?

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    struct CStruct *myStruct;
}
...
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (void)myMethod {
    delete myStruct, myStruct = 0;
}

@end
```

I can tell that the intent is to zero out the contents of the `struct` and then nil out the pointer to it, but what does that accomplish that the line below doesn't?

```
delete myStruct; myStruct = 0;
```

Comment: I'm inclined to guess that the warning is aimed at the possibility that whoever writes such code thinks that `delete` will operate on all the expressions of a comma-delimited list.  To the best of my (incomplete) knowledge, such an assumption is incorrect.  Furthermore, I am inclined to think that in your particular example, changing the comma to a semicolon will have no effect whatever on the observable behavior of the code.

Comment: "but what does that accomplish that the line below doesn't?" - it obfuscates the code. I'll disagree with @JohnBollinger slightly, I suspect the compiler writers know there are few good uses for the comma operator and its easily misunderstood, while the code writer was being "clever" - but then maybe I'm just a cynic ;-). Use the semicolon.

Comment: [myStruct release]; myStruct=nil; is the correct way. :D

Comment: @GeneCode it’s a C struct, not an Objective-C object, and the project is ARC.

Comment: Then why did you add objective-c tag to your question? ;)

Comment: @GeneCode I’m not saying you’re wrong, just making sure you caught that. It’s still in an Objective-C class, so I thought that might have some bearing on the answer.